# Custom Log4Net appender, specify where to find username

Tags: .net, log4net, appender

I've got a custom WcfAppender used by various projects (wpf, web etc). I want to log the username, however different technologies are used by the projects (windows authentication, federated security etc) and I don't want to write tightly coupled code, to the specific authentication technology. Can I somehow tell the appender how to find the username, by setting an action or similar? What are best practices in regards to custom log4net appenders?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question about a year ago but I"m not sure that there is a great solution other than using `ThreadContext` and setting a variable that stores the username on every single wcf call like this:

```
//You would need to get currentUserLoggedIn 
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["user"] = currentUserLoggedIn;
```

Here is my old question and there is an answer but this solution didn't work for me.  Maybe it will for you:

[log4net using ThreadContext.Properties in wcf PerSession service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047889/log4net-using-threadcontext-properties-in-wcf-persession-service)